# Continuity of real function on [a, b](real analysis)

Tags: analysis

Let I:=[a, b] and let f:I-> R be a continuous  function  on I such that for x in I there exists y in I such that |f(y)|<1/2|f(y)|. Prove there exists a point c in I such that f( c)=0.
I want to solve it intermediate value theorem but canot define proper f.

Comment: Perhaps of interest https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399300/existence-of-a-root-for-a-specific-function/3399334?noredirect=1#comment6992932_3399334

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1=b$. Prove by induction that there exist points $x_2,x_3,..$ with $|f(x_n)| \leq \frac 1 {2^{n-1}} |f(b)|$ $\cdots$ (1). By compactness there is a subsequence of $(x_n)$ which converges to  some point $c$ and we have $f(c)=0$ by continuity.

Avoiding compactness: If there is no such $c$ then $f$ is always positive or always negative. In the first case $f$ has a positive minimum. This contradicts inequlaity (1). The second case is similar.